# Pattern matching with Alternative empty or Applicative pure

Tags: haskell, typeclass, alternative-functor

I know it is possible, to pattern match against (named) constructors like so:

```hs
f1 :: Maybe a -> Bool
f1 Nothing = False
f1 (Just x) = True -- in reality have something that uses x here

f2 :: [a] -> Int
f2 [] = False
f2 x = True
```

How can I write such a function for general `Alternative`s similar to

```hs
f :: (Alternative m) => m a -> Bool
f empty = False
f x = True
```

If I try this, I get the error `Parse error in pattern: empty`. Which makes sense, I guess, as `empty` as a function here and not a constructor. But how can I accomplish this for general `Alternative`s idiomatically?

**Edit 1:**
My actual goal is to define a `Monad` instance (and probably also a `MonadPlus` instance) for a custom result type. Instead of the basic `Either Error Result` type, it should support a `Maybe Error` (and if possible also other `Alternative`s like `[Error]`) as error type and also some `Applicative` as result type in order to support lazy evaluation, for example with the result type `(Maybe Error, [Tokens])` of a tokenizer.

I'd like something similar to

```hs
instance (Alterantive mErr, Applicative mRes) => Monad (mErr e, mRes a) where
  return x = (empty, pure x)
  (empty, pure x) >>= f = f x
  (err, x) >>= f = (err, x)
```

Comment: `empty` isn't a function; it's a value. But it's the *name* of a value, not a constructor that *creates* the value.

Comment: @chepner out of curiosity, is there any difference between values and functions? Haskell's type system does not seem to make any. At least that's my novice take on it.

Comment: Well, all functions are values, but not all values are functions. A function has a type created by the `(->)` operator, and `f a` isn't necessarily such a type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is:

```
f :: (Eq (m a), Alternative m) => m a -> Bool
f x | x == empty = False
    | otherwise = True
```

Answer (score 2):

It is in fact possible using `-XPatternSynonyms` and `-XViewPatterns`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
import Control.Applicative (empty)

pattern Empty :: (Eq (m a), Alternative m) => m a
pattern Empty <- ((==) empty -> True)

f :: (Eq (m a), Alternative m) => m a -> Bool
f Empty = False
f _ = True
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you're intending.  Here, `empty` is an unbound variable (as if you'd written `pattern Empty <- x`, and the pattern always matches, so `f [1,2,3]` returns `False`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Answer has been adjusted.

Comment: Again, still doesn't work. If you want to do what @mithrandi's doing, `pattern Empty <- ((empty ==) -> True)`. You need that `Eq`.

Answer (score 1):

Slipping in an `Eq` constraint, as in [mithrandi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60303668/2751851), is indeed the best that can be done. In any case, it is worth emphasising that it comes at a cost: we are now stuck with an `Eq` constant that would be unnecessary were we merely pattern match against, say, `[]` or `Nothing`. A common way to avoid this problem is using `null :: Foldable t => t a -> Bool`. Here, however, that option is not great either, as `Foldable` is largely unrelated to `Alternative` and rather alien to your use case. In particular, there is no guarantee that, in the general case, there will be just one value for which `null` holds, which means it might conceivably hold for values that aren't the `empty` of the relevant `Alternative` instance.

Ultimately, then, the only tool that would fully fit the requirements might well be some `Alternative` subclass with an `isEmpty` method. I don't think that exists anywhere, and the power-to-weight ratio doesn't seem encouraging when it comes to conjuring such a thing.